# Can't doseq all entries

Tags: clojure

When I apply `doseq` with `transient` map to `java.util.HashMap`, I can always acquire only 8 entries.
How can I acquire all the entries?

```
user=> (def tmp-hash (doto (new java.util.HashMap) (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2) (.put "c" 3) (.put "d" 4) (.put "e" 5) (.put "f" 6) (.put "g" 7) (.put "h" 8) (.put "i" 9) (.put "j" 10))
user=> (let [t (transient {})] (doseq [[k v] tmp-hash] (assoc! t k v)) (persistent! t))
{"a" 1, "b" 2, "c" 3, "d" 4, "e" 5, "f" 6, "g" 7, "h" 8}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when ArrayMap's 8-element threshold is exceeded, a new HashMap is created - which [is returned](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentArrayMap.java#L419) as the return value of `assoc!`, which you are discarding in your code.

Instead of using the same object reference after `assoc!`, you should [use the return value](https://clojure.org/reference/transients#_how_they_work) of `assoc!` to work with the transient structure:

```
(persistent! (reduce (fn [acc [k v]]
                       (assoc! acc k v))
                     (transient {}) tmp-hash))
```